# How to route two subnets to the internet via a linux box acting as router and proxy

Tags: routing, subnet

I have a linux box that acts as router, DHCP server, and proxy. On my LAN side I need two subnets to have enough IPs: 192.168.100.0 - 192.168.101.255 - is the range I need. Both subnets must be able to reach the internet through my linux box,

On eth1 (em1) I have my internet modem connected with a static IP.

On eth2 (em2) I have my LAN connected with the following settings:

- IP address: 192.168.100.1
- Broadcast address: 192.168.101.255
- Subnet mask: 255.255.254.0
- Default gateway: 192.168.100.1

My routing table is as follows:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         56343ffe.rev.st 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em1
86.52.0.0       *               255.255.192.0   U     1      0        0 em1
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.254.0   U     1      0        0 em2
192.168.101.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em2
```

All traffic from port 80 is redirected to my proxy in shorewall - and this works fine - all hosts can access websites, YouTube etc. (port 80). All other traffic is masqueraded -
but traffic to other ports is a problem - e.g. Microsoft's DRM license server AVG update server - unreachable!? But I believe something is misconfigured in the routing table ?? My firewall accepts all outbound traffic after redirecting port 80 traffic.

Edit - output from my firewall (I have substituted the numbers in the internet address with xxx.xxx):

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
dnat       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
em1_masq   all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain dnat (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
loc_dnat   all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain em1_masq (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
SNAT       all  --  192.168.100.0/24     anywhere             to:86.52.xxx.xxx
SNAT       all  --  192.168.101.0/24     anywhere             to:86.52.xxx.xxx

Chain loc_dnat (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  192.168.100.0/24     anywhere             multiport dports http,squid redir ports 8080
REDIRECT   tcp  --  192.168.101.0/24     anywhere             multiport dports http,squid redir ports 8080
```

Comment: "enought" — whaht?

Comment: so the linux box is the firewall too? What firewall software are you using? Can you output the firewall rules to add to the question? Are you also asking if the two ip ranges you specify will have 'enough' hosts?

Comment: What's this about two subnets? Your question describes only one subnet, 192.168.100.0/23.

Comment: I use shorewall as firewall. I have 510 hosts and that's enough. I thought the problem was that it is two different subnets if you say 192.168.100.x and 192.168.101.x - but I'm new to this :-(

Answer (score 1):

You will have to NAT (masquerade) them.
And there you fail.
You say it is masqueraded, but obviously that isn't working.
(Port 80 does work because it gets proxied.)

There is some configuration on the NAT or the firewall (possibly BOTH) not correct.

P.S. You don't need that last routing line. It's already covered by the one above it.

Comment: I have the folowing in the masq file in shorewall (I have substitued the last digits with xxx)

INTERFACE:DEST         SOURCE          ADDRESS         PROTO   PORT(S) IPSEC   MARK    USER/   SWITCH
#                                                                                       GROUP
em1     192.168.100.0/24        86.52.xxx.xxx

em1     192.168.101.0/24        86.52.xxx.xxx

Comment: Doesn't I need some kind of localhost in the routing table ?? 127.0.0.1 ??